# Call to undefined function settings_fields() in boiler plate plugin structure

Tags: php, wordpress, boilerplate

I am creating plugin on base of boiler plate structure and i am trying to create admin menu page, but i am getting an error.
Below is my code.

below code in class-plugin-name.php inside admin hook,

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_menu', $plugin_admin, 'define_admin_page' );
$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_init', $plugin_admin, 'register_setting' );
```

inside class-plugin-name-admin.php  ,

```
public function define_admin_page(){

        add_menu_page(
          __('SEO Boost', 'seo-boost'), 
          __('SEO Boost', 'seo-boost'), 
          'manage_options', 
          'seo-boost', 
          array(&$this, 'seo_boost_page_callback')
        );        
    }

    public function seo_boost_page_callback(){
        include_once 'partials/plugin-name-admin-display.php';
    }

    public function register_setting(){
        add_settings_section(
               $this->option_name.'_general-section',
               __( 'General', 'seo-boost' ), 
               array( $this, $this->option_name . '_general_line' ), 
               $this->plugin_name
               );

    add_settings_field(
           $this->option_name . '_text', 
           __("Text box label:", 'seo-boost'), 
           array( $this, $this->option_name . '_text_api_element' ),    
          $this->plugin_name, 
          $this->option_name.'general-section',
          array( 'label_for' => $this->option_name . '_text' )
          );

    register_setting($this->option_name.'general-section', $this->option_name . '_text');           

    }

    public function seo_boost_general_line(){
        echo '<p>' . __( 'Please change the settings accordingly.', 'outdated-notice' ) . '</p>';
    }

    public function seo_boost_text_api_element(){
        $text = get_option( $this->option_name . '_text' );
        echo '<input type="text" name="' . $this->option_name . '_text' . '" id="' . $this->option_name . '_text' . '" value="' . $text . '"> ' . __( 'text', 'seo-boost' );
    }
```

inside plugin-name-admin-display.php there is code for display admin page form fields,

```
<div class="wrap">
            <h1><?php _e('Seo Settings', 'seo-boost'); ?></h1>
             <form action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php       
        settings_fields($this->option_name.'_general-section');
        do_settings_sections($this->plugin_name);
        submit_button(); ?>             
            </form>
        </div>
```

But i am getting an error of Fatal error:

Call to undefined function settings_fields() in plugin-name-admin-display.php on line 20

I am using ref from this link to create plugin.
[REf. plugin](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate-part-2-developing-a-plugin/)

Comment: the function name you have registered is define_setting_fields but you are writting setting_fields and calling it. then how will the script get the function?

Comment: Check this out - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_fields at the bottom of this page, you will have similar functions to deal with.

Comment: do_settings_sections($this->plugin_name,$this->option_name.'_general-section');

try this @AshPatel

Comment: @Exprator: not working. :(

Comment: what is it showing now?

Comment: @Exprator: i have added ref link from which i have been trying to implement functionality.

Comment: same error displaying.

Comment: function not found error?

Comment: settings_fields( $this->plugin_name );
do_settings_sections( $this->plugin_name );

add this 2 line and remove the old 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144030/discussion-between-ash-patel-and-exprator).

Comment: @Exprator: can we go to chat so we can resolve quickly?

Comment: it will be of no use i guess. because from what i saw in your code i can say upto what i said. if now its not working, do one thing follow the full tutorial you posted

Answer (score -3):

Incredibly, you must add a space in between the parenthesis for the call to work. So instead of:

```
settings_fields($this->option_name.'_general-section');
```

you should code it as:

```
settings_fields( $this->option_name.'_general-section' );
```

Comment: Space between parenthesis and argument does not influence code functionality by any way.